How can I get an AWS anomaly at the resource-level rather than service-level?
Currently, I am using the CostExplorer API to retrieve anomalies within AWS. However, when I call
get_anomalies(), this is the lowest level of detail I can get from the anomaly:
'RootCauses': [
                {
                    'Service': 'string',
                    'Region': 'string',
                    'LinkedAccount': 'string',
                    'UsageType': 'string',
                    'LinkedAccountName': 'string'
                },
            ]

As you can see, only the service is given and not the resource with an ARN. Are there any other APIs within AWS for retrieving resource-level anomalies?
I looked at methods within CostExplorer API and CloudWatch API but nothing suited my use case.
